# Excel Interop ( insert image) in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: excel, office-interop, excel-interop

We are migrating our web application from Windows 2003 to windows 2012 R2.

The application has an excel report functionality. We open the excel ( template file) using Interop and write some data out and insert an image from a specific folder in the server.

The MS office version is 2007. The strange thing is the insert image functionality works only when the image size is less than 20 kb, as soon as the application tries to insert an image greater than 20 kb like 250 kb, the system hangs as if it is not getting enough memory to do the job and the excel.exe hangs in task manager.

In the Dcomcnfg, the excel is running under "Launching User" identity.

The IIS App Pool is using the network service to run the application.

The code to insert image is shown below, however since it is working in Windows 2003, we have not changed anything

```
public void InsertImage(string imagePath, float leftPosition, float topPosition, float   imageWidth, float heightImage)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(imagePath))
            throw new   OfficeHelperException(OfficeHelperException.ExceptionType.ImageFileNotFound);

        WorkingSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(
            imagePath,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue,
            leftPosition,
            topPosition,
            imageWidth,
            heightImage);
    }
```

Is there any memory allocation setting in the new windows 2012 r2? The web application has other excel reports which don't have an image export and they are working fine.

We tried to remove this insert image functionality by putting a macro inside the template file which will insert the image and called the macro from interop. It works on local machine, but on server again it is hanging when the image size is bigger than 20 kb.

We are stuck with this, and not sure of any known problem with windows server 2012 R2 related to excel interop. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: We found your post because we are in almost the exact situation and facing the same problem...just hangs on AddPicture call for some images.  Did you find the issue/resolution?

Comment: As per @B17's answer, [Server-Side automation of Office is not supported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757), try using the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) instead of Interop.

Answer (score 0):

I set true the parameter MsoTriState LinkToFile and works fine! I'm using Win 2012 R2 and Excel 2010 x64.

Ex:

```
oHoja.Shapes.AddPicture(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/logos/57/teix.png", 
     MsoTriState.msoCTrue, MsoTriState.msoCTrue,float.Parse(3.ToString()), 
     float.Parse(65.ToString()), 
     float.Parse("113"), 
     float.Parse("54"));
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue exactly. I fixed it by installing MS Office 2013.